# Whenever I create a react app, it fails to compile

Tags: node.js, reactjs

After running npx create-react-app and then npm start, I keep getting this error

```
./src/index.css (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-oneOf-4-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./src/index.css)
TypeError: Cannot read property 'prefix_exceptions' of undefined
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
```

I have tried reinstalling multiple times but can't get around this error.

Comment: Which version of Node.js do you have installed?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the issue was, but installing and starting with yarn bypassed the issue.